# FFT derivatives using Numpy and the Nyquist frequency

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am having trouble understanding Numpy's behavior regarding the Nyquist frequency. Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 21)[:-1]
k=np.fft.rfftfreq(len(x), d=x[1]-x[0])

FFT=np.fft.rfft(x)

x1=np.fft.irfft(1j*k*FFT)
FFT[-1]+=1e5
x2=np.fft.irfft(1j*k*FFT)

print(np.allclose(x1,x2))
```

Prints `True`. So apparently it doesn't matter what I do with the Nyquist frequency in `FFT`, the result is always the same and the change is ignored. Curiously, this does not happen when trying to just recover the function (no derivation):

```
x1=np.fft.irfft(FFT)
FFT[-1]+=1e5
x2=np.fft.irfft(FFT)

print(np.allclose(x1,x2))
```

prints `False`.

I may be misunderstanding what the Nyquist frequency is here (Wikipedia and other sources weren't very helpful) but aren't both results supposed to be affected by a change in the Nyquist frequency? The closest explanation I can find is that the Nyquist frequency is supposed to be a real number, but still doesn't seem to explain both behaviors.

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm trying to reproduce results that I know are correct from a [Fortran code](http://www.fftw.org) that does do some stuff with the Nyquist frequency wen differentiating. My results are always about 1% off and I'm guessing this is the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `r` in `np.fft.rfft()` indicates that you are using the DFT on real input. But if that is not True, you will get *unexpected* behaviors like this one. Just use `fft` functions for complex values. As a side note, always try to inspect your data.

**EDIT** (additional explanation):

In particular, when you calculate the "DFT for real  inputs" you are enforcing certain properties to your data, i.e.  the (D)FT of real valued function, implies that the (D)FT transform is Hermitian-symmetric, and hence the negative (D)FT coefficients are redundant, so `rfft` and later `irfft` are optimized for the computation under this assumption.
See their documentations [`np.fft.rfft()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html) and [`np.fft.irfft()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfft.html) for more information.

Briefly, because of this expected parity, half of your coefficients (the negative ones) will not be computed by `np.fft.rfft()` and because of parity of the (D)FT transform, the first component is purely real (by definition) and the last component is also purely real (for convenience).
Because of the `1j` multiplication, whatever was purely real is now purely imaginary (and viceversa) in the subsequent `irfft` calls.
Since the `irfft()` will ignore the imaginary part of the first and last components, your statement will not affect its result.

Comment: The input variable is real though. What is complex is the `FFT` after the `fft.rfft` transformation (with the exception of the first and last frequencies. I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: I have added some more explanation on what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks I get it now. Doesn't particularly help my case because the 1% error is still there but it's good to know that's not it.

Comment: For the "1%" error you are getting from the FORTRAN code, I'd suggest either you post the code for help in translating or you could try using `f2py`.